# Buying a Sunpass after Passing a Toll on 836

Tags: usa, driving, florida, tolls

Didn't have a Sunpass when I passed a toll on 836. Bought a Sunpass afterwards. Can toll be charged retroactive?

Answer (score 2):

More than likely they took a photo of your license tag and will send the bill to whomever the car's registered owner is.

I am not sure, but think 836 is part of MDX, Miami Dade Expressway system which is separate from SunPass, but which does accept SunPass as a form of payment when driving through toll plazas.  I think you will need to pay the bill directly to MDX and will not be able to bill SunPass retroactively.